# Parsing a txt file and outputting to an xlsx file using openpyxl

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to parse a large text from witch I need some specific data to be outputted to an xlsx file on two columns.

The text I need to parse looks like this:

```
[memcpy.pointer_arithmetic.5] line 33 pointer relation: pointer outside object bounds in (const char *)pvItemToQueue$link1: SUCCESS
```

And I want to look like this:
[image]

I have issues in parsing the text, I need `split[0]` and `split[1]` in one column and `split[2]` in one column, I have tried something like this (just the part with the 1st column):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet("Queue", 0)
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Task", 1)
with open('CBMC_Queue_Results.txt', 'r') as input:
    list1 = [line for line in input]
ws = wb['Queue']
ws["A1"] = "Tests"
row = 2
column = 1

for line in list1:
    if not "[" in line:
        continue
    split = line.split(':')
    ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = split[0] + split[1]
    row += 1

wb.save('All_Results.xlsx')
```

I receive the following error:

```
    ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = split[0] + split[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I just leave `split[0]` it works and puts in my xlsx file the first part of the list (e.g. [memcpy.pointer_arithmetic.5] line 33 pointer relation ) I do not understand why I do not have access to the second and third element from the list.

With this simple code, it prints SUCCESS:

```
text = '''[memcpy.pointer_arithmetic.5] line 33 pointer relation: pointer outside object bounds in (const char *)pvItemToQueue$link1: SUCCESS'''
split = text.split(':')

print(split[2])
```

Could you please let me know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that the data you're processing is not the data you expect. In other words, there are not enough `:` characters in the line you're processing to split it into 3 list elements. This is what's throwing the index error.

Just as a general troubleshooting step, throw a `print` statement before the line that throws the error, printing out the data the error is thrown on.

Since we here on SO don't know exactly what the data is that causes the error, we cannot directly assist you. I do have some suggestions for your code to make it a bit more robust though. I gather from your code and the provided sample data that you want to put everything from each line that has a `[` character in two different columns, split on the last `:` character. Try the code below.

```py
testdata = '''[memcpy.pointer_arithmetic.5] line 33 pointer relation: pointer outside object bounds in (const char *)pvItemToQueue$link1: SUCCESS
[memcpy.pointer_arithmetic.5] line 33 pointer relation: pointer outside object bounds in (const char *)pvItemToQueue$link1: SUCCESS'''


for line in testdata.split("\n"):
    if not "[" in line:
        continue
    columndata = ":".join(line.split(':')[:-1]) # now it doesn't matter how many : characters there are
    success = line.split(":")[-1].strip()  # clean spaces
    print(columndata)
    print(success)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve it, the issue was with input file, the was line of text which had only one ":", manage to overcome this issue with this code:

```
if line.startswith("["): 
        splitline = line.split(':')
        del splitline[-1]
        try:
            ws.cell(row=row, column=columnA).value = splitline[0] + ":" + splitline[1]
        except:
            ws.cell(row=row, column=columnA).value = splitline[0]
        ws.column_dimensions['A'].width = 150
        ws.cell(row=row, column=columnB).value = line.split(":")[-1]
        row += 1
```

Thanks for your prompt answer.

Br,
Stephan